# Rails pipeline javascript trying to call an init prototype - reference error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

given a js file in the pipeline

```
//= require pages-js/pages.frontend.js
```

this js file being a simple class + proto

```
    (function($) {
    var Pages = function() {
        this.$body = $('body');
        ... /...
    }
    Pages.prototype.initRevealFooter = function() {
        ... /...
    }
    // Call initializers
    Pages.prototype.init = function() {
          .... 
         this.initRevealFooter();
    }
    $.Pages = new Pages();
    $.Pages.Constructor = Pages;
})(window.jQuery);
```

I would like to call the initialiser from my application init.coffee

```
window.App ||= {}
App.init = ->
  alert "Page changed"
  $.Pages = new Pages()
  $.Pages.init()
```

$(document).on "page:change", ->
     App.init()

I get the alert 'Page changed', but also an error in the web console

```
Reference error: Cannot find variable: Pages
```

How can I make this Pages function known in my init.coffee file ?

Answer (score 0):

should remove the new Pages() line and write only :

```
window.App ||= {}
#
App.init = ->
   $.Pages.init()
#
$(document).on "page:change", ->
   App.init()
```